# In spark UI my jobs and stages screen show blank, what could have been wrong?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using spark 2.4.3 v.
I have a spark sql streaming job to consume data from my kafka topic.

my spark job running on a aws emr cluster.
my job has following configuration

```
--driver-memory 4g \
--driver-cores 2 \
--num-executors 20 \
--executor-cores 2 \
--executor-memory 768m \
```

Even though my job started and running fine , when checked the spark-UI , Jobs & Stages pages showing empty screen. What is wrong here and how to fix it ?

[image]

Sometimes it show when I reduce --executor-memory 512m \

What is wrong here and how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you write server specifications?

Comment: I mean your server memory specifications. Maybe you can not create executors because of memory size. Please check executors page when you cant see any jobs on ui. If there is no executor, that means you are not consuming kafka partitions.

Comment: Did you find out why was Stages tab empty? Thanks!

Comment: I've got the same issue, and have no idea. Maybe something related to log dependencies?